# PHP Zip module doesn't load

Tags: nginx, centos, php7, zip

I use PHP 7.4 and Nginx 1.16.1 and i want to enable php-zip in my server because a wordpress plugin required it:

[image]

I installed zip module (php-pecl-zip-1.19.1-1.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64). If i type `php --modules` zip extensions exists:

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
tokenizer
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

But in phpinfo or wordpress seems that zip extensions is off. What's the problem?

I have zip and unzip packages installed.

I install php-zip from remi repo:

```
[root@CentOS-78-64-minimal php.d]# yum install php-zip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: linux.darkpenguin.net
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * remi-php74: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
Package php-pecl-zip-1.19.1-1.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: Check this forum topic: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270790&tstart=0

Comment: restart the php-fpm service....

Comment: I try to restart php-fpm and fully server but problem persists